# How to change layout of only selected listview row with in onitemclicklistener of listview

Tags: android, listview, custom-adapter

I need to create `ListView` like `Samsung Contact List`. And I need to show custom layout for that row while that row is `swiped`. And also need to show contact detail at background of that row. Please give me some ideas or reference.

Thank You.

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(stationSelectionListener);
final ListSwipeDetector listSwipeDetector=new ListSwipeDetector();
list.setOnTouchListener(listSwipeDetector);
new UserAndMessageCount(StationListActivity.this).execute();
list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                if (listSwipeDetector.swipeDetected()){
                    Toast.makeText(StationListActivity.this,"sWIPE1",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    LayoutInflater inflater=(LayoutInflater)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                    View viewNew=inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_flow_common_page, null);
                    view=viewNew;
                } 
                else {
                    ConstantValues.STATION_NAME=((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView)).getText().toString();
                    LayoutInflater inflater=(LayoutInflater)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                    View viewNew=inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_flow_common_page, null);
                    //startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), StationSelectionActivity.class));
                }
            }
    });
    list.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {
            if (listSwipeDetector.swipeDetected()){
                Toast.makeText(StationListActivity.this,"sWIPE3",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(StationListActivity.this,"sWIPE4",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Within `onItemClickListener`, you can implement `onItemClick (AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)`. If you retrieve the `view`, you can make the changes you need for it when the user clicks on that item.

For swiping, you can modify your adapter's `getItem()` function and add a `GestureListener` or something like [this code](https://github.com/krishjlk/android-listview-swipe-delete-example-sample-tuorial). Then you can listen for swipes and act accordingly.

Comment: I'm sorry, I cann't able to create my view. I know upto listview swipe but don't know how to change the selected row of the listview.

Comment: Where are you trying to change the selected row? Inside `getItem()`? Or inside `onItemClick()`?

Comment: I don't know about getItem() so i was tried with onItemClick().

Comment: The second argument, `view`, of `onItemClick()` is that item's row. You can then cast it to whatever view it is and use `findViewById()` to access other views in that row.