# Changing Layout of clicked item in ListView, throws NullPointerException

Tags: android, listview

when writing an app for me and my roommates to calculate our food-payments I got stuck on such problem:

when adding new payment, you:
1) select name from RadioGroup
2) give value 
3) give description (or leave default 'opis')

then after pressing button "DODAJ" it shows as new item in ListView with certain format. Now the problem begins:

I want to make it so when I click on a Item in this list, i will slightly change format of this certain item (in NowaWplata class I got extra time to be displayed) which I got in another .xml layout file. I tried 2 different approaches:
one is commented in the bottom of my code (I tried it from this topic [Change layout of selected list item in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25347465/change-layout-of-selected-list-item-in-android)), and the other one is in overriden onItemClick method - neither of them worked

error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.example.lukasz.dom.MainActivity.onItemClick
```

here

```
        relativeLayoutInflate.addView(child);
```

in main activity (onClick only for 'lukasz', same for 'marcelina' and 'karolina'):

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if (v == addNewPaymentButton) {
            //checking which button from RadioGroup is checked and adding new payment to certain person
            int checkedRadioButtonId = members.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
            switch (checkedRadioButtonId) {

                //if Lukasz button is pressed, do:
                case R.id.lukaszRadioButton:
                    if (lukaszRadioButton.isChecked()) {

                        //add value from addNewPaymentButton to tempLukasz
                        try {
                            tempLukasz += valueOf(newPaymentValue.getText().toString());
                        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                        }

                        //seting new value to money spent by lukasz
                        String sumaLukasza = getString(R.string.money_spent_by_lukasz);
                        sumaLukasza = String.format(sumaLukasza, tempLukasz);
                        moneySpentByLukasz.setText(sumaLukasza);

                        //adding new payment to list of all payments with flag 'int == 1' to set color to RED
                        NowaWplata newPayment = new NowaWplata(lukaszRadioButton.getText().toString(), newPaymentValue.getText().toString(), descriptionOfNewPayment.getText().toString(), 1);
                        NowaWplata.setWplaty(newPayment);
                        listView.setAdapter(new NewPaymentAdapter(this, R.layout.new_list_item_layout, NowaWplata.getWplaty()));

                    }
                    break;
}


    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        TextView hourDate = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.hoursDateFieldInSelectedListItem);
        TextView dayDate = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.daysDateFieldInSelectedListItem);
        TextView name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.nameFieldInSelectedListItem);
        TextView value = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.valueFieldInSelectedListItem);
        TextView description = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.descriptionFieldInSelectedListItem);

        RelativeLayout relativeLayoutInflate = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.layoutOfSelectedListItem);
        NowaWplata newPayment = (NowaWplata) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);
        View child = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.selected_list_item, null);
        relativeLayoutInflate.addView(child);


        hourDate.setText("[" + newPayment.getHourDate() + "]");
        dayDate.setText(newPayment.getDayDate());
        name.setText(newPayment.getOsoba());
        value.setText(newPayment.getWplata() + "zł");
        description.setText(newPayment.getOpis());


    }
}

//custom adapter class
 class NewPaymentAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<NowaWplata> {

    public LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

    //custom adapter's constructor with values
    public NewPaymentAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, List<NowaWplata> wplaty) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, wplaty);
        layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View view = convertView;
        NowaWplata newPayment = getItem(position);
        Holder holder = null;

//            private int position;
//            public void selectedItem(int position)
//            {
//                this.position = position;
//            }

        //if there are no items in list - add 1st item
        if (view == null) {
            view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.new_list_item_layout, null);

            TextView name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.osobaWplata);
            TextView value = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.kwotaWplata);
            TextView description = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.opisWplata);

            holder = new Holder(name, value, description);
            view.setTag(holder);
        }
        // if there are items in list get holder tag
        else {
            holder = (Holder) view.getTag();
        }

        //setting text to a new list item
        holder.osoba.setText("[" + newPayment.getDate() + "]  " + newPayment.getOsoba());
        holder.kwota.setText(newPayment.getWplata() + "zł");
        holder.opis.setText(newPayment.getOpis());

        //setting different color to Lukasz/Marcelina/Karolina text
        if (newPayment.getFlag() == 1) {
            holder.osoba.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        } else if (newPayment.getFlag() == 2) {
            holder.osoba.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
        } else if (newPayment.getFlag() == 3) {
            holder.osoba.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
        }
        //setting color to payment's value
        holder.kwota.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);

//            if (this.position == position) {
//                View view2;
//                view2 = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.selected_list_item, null);
//
//                TextView hourDate = (TextView) view2.findViewById(R.id.hoursDateFieldInSelectedListItem);
//                TextView dayDate = (TextView) view2.findViewById(R.id.daysDateFieldInSelectedListItem);
//                TextView name = (TextView) view2.findViewById(R.id.nameFieldInSelectedListItem);
//                TextView value = (TextView) view2.findViewById(R.id.valueFieldInSelectedListItem);
//                TextView description = (TextView) view2.findViewById(R.id.descriptionFieldInSelectedListItem);
//
//                hourDate.setText("[" + newPayment.getHourDate() + "]");
//                dayDate.setText(newPayment.getDayDate());
//                name.setText(newPayment.getOsoba());
//                value.setText(newPayment.getWplata() + "zł");
//                description.setText(newPayment.getOpis());
//
//                return view2;
//            }

        return view;
    }
}
```

this is the main XML part with the ListView

```
   <ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tableLayout"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_above="@+id/newPaymentValue"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/tableLayout"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/tableLayout"
    android:choiceMode="none"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:transcriptMode="disabled"/>
```

this is the xml of a new item in list

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/layoutOfSelectedListItem">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:id="@+id/hoursDateFieldInSelectedListItem"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:textSize="18dp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:id="@+id/daysDateFieldInSelectedListItem"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textSize="18dp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:id="@+id/nameFieldInSelectedListItem"
    android:layout_below="@+id/hoursDateFieldInSelectedListItem"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/daysDateFieldInSelectedListItem"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/daysDateFieldInSelectedListItem"
    android:textSize="18dp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:id="@+id/valueFieldInSelectedListItem"
    android:layout_below="@+id/daysDateFieldInSelectedListItem"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:textSize="22dp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:id="@+id/descriptionFieldInSelectedListItem"
    android:layout_below="@+id/nameFieldInSelectedListItem"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:textSize="14dp" />
```

Comment: If u want me to dive in this BIG code u have to pay me :) only share relative code & affected area

Comment: I cut the irrelevant parts of the code, sorry

Comment: In which line, are you getting the error?

Comment: it's said above
error is here:
" relativeLayoutInflate.addView(child);"