# Changing layout of an ListView item when pressing it

Tags: android, listview

when writing an app for me and my roommates to calculate our food-payments I got stuck on such problem:

when adding new payment, you:
1) select name from RadioGroup
2) give value 
3) give description (or leave default 'opis')

then after pressing button "DODAJ" it shows as new item in ListView with certain format. Now the problem begins:

I want to make it so when I click on a Item in this list, i will slightly change format of this certain item (in NowaWplata class I got extra time to be displayed) which I got in another .xml layout file, and when pressing it again it should go back to 'normal' layout.
I tried 2 different approaches, one is commented in the bottom of my code (I tried it from this topic [Change layout of selected list item in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25347465/change-layout-of-selected-list-item-in-android)), and the other one is in overriden onItemClick method - neither of them worked

compiler says that the error is :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.example.lukasz.dom.MainActivity.onItemClick
```

in this line of code:

```
        relativeLayoutInflate.addView(child);
```

in main activity (onClick only for 'lukasz', same for 'marcelina' and 'karolina'):

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if (v == addNewPaymentButton) {
            //checking which button from RadioGroup is checked and adding new payment to certain person
            int checkedRadioButtonId = members.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
            switch (checkedRadioButtonId) {

                //if Lukasz button is pressed, do:
                case R.id.lukaszRadioButton:
                    if (lukaszRadioButton.isChecked()) {

                        //add value from addNewPaymentButton to tempLukasz
                        try {
                            tempLukasz += valueOf(newPaymentValue.getText().toString());
                        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                        }

                        //seting new value to money spent by lukasz
                        String sumaLukasza = getString(R.string.money_spent_by_lukasz);
                        sumaLukasza = String.format(sumaLukasza, tempLukasz);
                        moneySpentByLukasz.setText(sumaLukasza);

                        //adding new payment to list of all payments with flag 'int == 1' to set color to RED
                        NowaWplata newPayment = new NowaWplata(lukaszRadioButton.getText().toString(), newPaymentValue.getText().toString(), descriptionOfNewPayment.getText().toString(), 1);
                        NowaWplata.setWplaty(newPayment);
                        listView.setAdapter(new NewPaymentAdapter(this, R.layout.new_list_item_layout, NowaWplata.getWplaty()));

                    }
                    break;
}


    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        TextView hourDate = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.hoursDateFieldInSelectedListItem);
        TextView dayDate = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.daysDateFieldInSelectedListItem);
        TextView name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.nameFieldInSelectedListItem);
        TextView value = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.valueFieldInSelectedListItem);
        TextView description = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.descriptionFieldInSelectedListItem);

        RelativeLayout relativeLayoutInflate = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.layoutOfSelectedListItem);
        NowaWplata newPayment = (NowaWplata) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);
        View child = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.selected_list_item, null);
        relativeLayoutInflate.addView(child);


        hourDate.setText("[" + newPayment.getHourDate() + "]");
        dayDate.setText(newPayment.getDayDate());
        name.setText(newPayment.getOsoba());
        value.setText(newPayment.getWplata() + "zł");
        description.setText(newPayment.getOpis());


    }
}

//custom adapter class
 class NewPaymentAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<NowaWplata> {

    public LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

    //custom adapter's constructor with values
    public NewPaymentAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, List<NowaWplata> wplaty) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, wplaty);
        layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View view = convertView;
        NowaWplata newPayment = getItem(position);
        Holder holder = null;

//            private int position;
//            public void selectedItem(int position)
//            {
//                this.position = position;
//            }

        //if there are no items in list - add 1st item
        if (view == null) {
            view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.new_list_item_layout, null);

            TextView name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.osobaWplata);
            TextView value = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.kwotaWplata);
            TextView description = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.opisWplata);

            holder = new Holder(name, value, description);
            view.setTag(holder);
        }
        // if there are items in list get holder tag
        else {
            holder = (Holder) view.getTag();
        }

        //setting text to a new list item
        holder.osoba.setText("[" + newPayment.getDate() + "]  " + newPayment.getOsoba());
        holder.kwota.setText(newPayment.getWplata() + "zł");
        holder.opis.setText(newPayment.getOpis());

        //setting different color to Lukasz/Marcelina/Karolina text
        if (newPayment.getFlag() == 1) {
            holder.osoba.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        } else if (newPayment.getFlag() == 2) {
            holder.osoba.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
        } else if (newPayment.getFlag() == 3) {
            holder.osoba.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
        }
        //setting color to payment's value
        holder.kwota.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);

//            if (this.position == position) {
//                View view2;
//                view2 = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.selected_list_item, null);
//
//                TextView hourDate = (TextView) view2.findViewById(R.id.hoursDateFieldInSelectedListItem);
//                TextView dayDate = (TextView) view2.findViewById(R.id.daysDateFieldInSelectedListItem);
//                TextView name = (TextView) view2.findViewById(R.id.nameFieldInSelectedListItem);
//                TextView value = (TextView) view2.findViewById(R.id.valueFieldInSelectedListItem);
//                TextView description = (TextView) view2.findViewById(R.id.descriptionFieldInSelectedListItem);
//
//                hourDate.setText("[" + newPayment.getHourDate() + "]");
//                dayDate.setText(newPayment.getDayDate());
//                name.setText(newPayment.getOsoba());
//                value.setText(newPayment.getWplata() + "zł");
//                description.setText(newPayment.getOpis());
//
//                return view2;
//            }

        return view;
    }
}
```

this is the main XML part with the ListView

```
   <ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tableLayout"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_above="@+id/newPaymentValue"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/tableLayout"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/tableLayout"
    android:choiceMode="none"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:transcriptMode="disabled"/>
```

this is the xml of a new item in list

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/layoutOfSelectedListItem">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:id="@+id/hoursDateFieldInSelectedListItem"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:textSize="18dp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:id="@+id/daysDateFieldInSelectedListItem"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textSize="18dp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:id="@+id/nameFieldInSelectedListItem"
    android:layout_below="@+id/hoursDateFieldInSelectedListItem"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/daysDateFieldInSelectedListItem"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/daysDateFieldInSelectedListItem"
    android:textSize="18dp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:id="@+id/valueFieldInSelectedListItem"
    android:layout_below="@+id/daysDateFieldInSelectedListItem"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:textSize="22dp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:id="@+id/descriptionFieldInSelectedListItem"
    android:layout_below="@+id/nameFieldInSelectedListItem"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:textSize="14dp" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I have done that by adding extra layout.

ListItem:

```
<--Your listItem view--!>
<RelativeLayout>
    <--Your extra View--!>
    <LinearLayout
    android:tag="0"
    android:visibility="gone">
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

In your `OnItemClickListener` set the extra layout to visible and also set the tag accordingly to save the state of the extra view.

Comment: I've jsut started learning android and i am not sure if I understand it correctly. So I should add this 
   `<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:tag="0"
        android:id="@+id/extraLayout"
        android:visibility="gone">
    </LinearLayout>`

just under relative layout declaration in new_list_item_layout (not the SELECTED xml layout file, right?) and in OnItemClickListener i should write :       `child.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);` ?

Comment: yes, and in that linearlayout all your hideable view will be. you can use Relativelayout instead of linearLayout according to your needs.

Comment: oh wait, so u say I should place all the code from my "selected list item" XML to "new item list" XML and add these 2 lines 'tag' and 'visibility' ?
also to this part "and also set the tag accordingly to save the state of the extra view." the tag part should look the same as in getView method in the bottom of the MainActivity ?

Comment: The thing is you have to provide the code of your hideable View in the listItem with visibility set to "gone" and when you want to show it just set its visibility to "visible". So, Now your listItem.xml should have following code for:
a. Default view which will always be visible.
b. Hideable View that would be set to visible if needed.

Comment: you can use a boolean instead of tag. i used tags just for checking whether the view is visible or not.

Comment: I made new holder constructor with things that should be in the hidden list item, but dont know how to set a tag for it ? 
`if (view == null) {
            view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.new_list_item_layout, null);
 ...
...
...

            holder1 = new Holder(name, value, description);
            holder2 = new Holder(nameSelected, valueSelected, descriptionSelected, hourDateSelected, dayDateSelected);
            view.setTag(holder1);
            view.setTag(holder2);
        }
       holder1 = (Holder) view.getTag();
            holder2 = (Holder) view.getTag();
        }`

Comment: Have you achieved to show or hide the extraVIew onItemClick??

Comment: no, in my getView i got these 2 holders but it doesn't work as intended, should I somehow make components of the 'default' list item layout go invisible ?
            `view.setTag(R.id.TAG_ONLINE_ID_1, holder1);
            view.setTag(R.id.TAG_ONLINE_ID_2, holder2);
        }
        else {
            holder1 = (Holder) view.getTag(R.id.TAG_ONLINE_ID_1);
            holder2 = (Holder) view.getTag(R.id.TAG_ONLINE_ID_2);
        }`